# Find empty lists in nested list of lists

Tags: r, nested-lists

Given an arbitrarily nested list, how can I find if a list contains empty lists? Consider the following example:

`mylist <- list(list("foo", "bar", "baz", list(list())))`

I tried `rapply`, but that skips through lists. While I could use `lapply`, I'd need to know the level of nesting beforehand. For this exercise, I don't need to know where the list is (although that would be a bonus), I just need a way to detect if there is one.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, that's what I'm after

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about a function like this

```
has_empty_list <- function(x) {
    if(is.list(x)) {
        if (length(x)==0) {
            return(TRUE)
        } else {
            return(any(vapply(x, has_empty_list, logical(1))))
        }
    } else {
        return(FALSE)
    }
}
```

Basically we create a recursive function to look for lists of length 0.

```
has_empty_list( list(list("foo", "bar", "baz", list(list()))) )
# TRUE
has_empty_list( list(list("foo", "bar", "baz", list(list(4)))) )
# FALSE
```

And here's a modification to find the index of the empty list

```
find_empty_list <- function(x, index=c()) {
    if(is.list(x)) {
        #list
        if (length(x)==0) {
            if (length(index)==0) {
                return(0)
            } else {
                return(index)
            }
        } else {
            m <- Map(find_empty_list, x, lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) append(index,i)))
            # return the most deeply nested
            return( m[[which.max(lengths(m))]] )
        }
    } else {
        return(numeric())
    }
}
```

This should return a vector of the index that you can use to find the empty list. For example

```
( i <- find_empty_list(mylist) )
# [1] 1 4 1
mylist[[i]]
# list()
```

If the first parameter itself is an empty list, it will return 0

```
find_empty_list(list())
# 0
```

and if there is no empty list, it should return an empty vector

```
find_empty_list(list(1:3, list("c", a~b)))
# numeric()
```

Comment: I figured recursion would be a good way to solve it. One slight modification - I'd use `vapply(x, has_empty_list, logical(1))`.

Comment: @sebastian-c added another function to find the missing list as well

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. The one to find empty lists is great, but the one to find empty lists is a little trickier. It seems to have trouble with multiple empty lists (it seems to got for the most nested one).

Comment: True. If you want it to do something else, you should describe what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: One question, why `is.vector(x) & !is.atomic(x)` instead of `is.list(x)`?

Comment: `is.list` would probably work just as well. It's just oddly not the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Just a minor comment, I guess you can replace `sapply(m, length)` with `lengths(m)` (for recent R versions)

Answer (score 5):

Another convenient option to work with nested list is to use `data.tree` package:

```
library(data.tree)
nodes <- as.Node(mylist)
any(node$Get(function(node) length(as.list(node))) == 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: seems to be quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (an extension of base-`rrapply`):

```r
library(rrapply)

## check if any empty list exists
any(
  rrapply(mylist,
          classes = "list",
          condition = function(x) length(x) < 1,
          f = function(x) TRUE, 
          deflt = FALSE,
          how = "unlist"
  )
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

It is straightforward to update the above call to return the index vectors of any empty lists:

```r
## return flat list with position vectors of empty list
rrapply(mylist,
        classes = "list",
        condition = function(x) length(x) < 1,
        f = function(x, .xpos) .xpos, 
        how = "flatten"
)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 4 1
```

Here, we make use of the `.xpos` argument which evaluates to the position of the current list element under evaluation.

---

Note that this automatically returns all empty list positions instead of only one:

```r
mylist2 <- list(list("foo", list(), "baz", list(list())))

rrapply(mylist2,
        classes = "list",
        condition = function(x) length(x) < 1,
        f = function(x, .xpos) .xpos, 
        how = "flatten"
)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 4 1

## using MrFlick's find_empty_list function
find_empty_list(mylist2)
#> [1] 1 4 1
```